# how to auto-adjust column width in related list?

Tags: related-list, service-cloud-console

[image]

I have requirement to auto-adjust column or display columns within 100 px so agent can at a glance see more information. Is it possible to give width to columns in the related list?

Answer (score 2):

There is no officialy supported way to tweak the column width of related lists. Usually the lists make a good job in using the screen real estate dynamically. Possibly outside the console they might do it slightly better.

Probably there would be ways to achieve what you want by hacking the UI - but in that use-case I can't see a reason which is strong enough to do it. Since that whitespace seems not doing much harm at all, I would recommend keeping it as it is.